# Power inductor maximum DC current rating

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor

I am selecting a power inductor for my power supply. The only significant source of current draw is a servo motor that draws about 200mA - 1A for 500 ms for less than 10 times a day.

Consider the following power inductor: [Bourns SRN4018](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/54/SRN4018-478895.pdf). Suppose I use the 33 uH inductor that has an Irms rating of 700 mA, how long can I pass 900 mA rms (for example) through the power inductor before the power inductor dies? I don't see this information in the power inductor datasheets I have seen (e.g. [Abracon](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/3/ASPI-4020S-253634.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

That inductor can survive 700mA RMS indefinitely provided you meet the ambient temperature specification.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I realize that I have asked the question in a silly way. My actual question is what if I have 900mA RMS for 0.5s? Will that burn the inductor? Or 1s? Is there any way to tell?

Comment: *That* inductor saturates at 0.75A, which may be a bigger problem than just the temperature rise due to a higher current.